# Shell Scripting Ternary operator to get string result

Tags: string, shell, scripting, ternary-operator

In shell scripting, I am using ternary operator like this:

```
(( numVar == numVal ? (resVar=1) : (resVar=0) ))
```

I watched shell scripting tutorial by Derek Banas and got the above syntax at 41:00 of the video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hwrnmQumtPw&t=73s

The above code works when we assign numbers to `resVar`, but if I try to assign a string to `resVar`, it always returns 0.

```
(( numVar == numVal ? (resVar="Yop") : (resVar="Nop") ))
```

and also tried

```
resVar=$(( numVar == numVal ? (echo "Yop") : (echo "Nop") ))
```

So which is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't tell us what shell you use but it's possible you use
`bash` or something similar. Ternary operator in `Bash` works only with numbers as
explained in `man bash` under `ARITHMETIC EVALUATION` section:

> The shell allows arithmetic expressions to be evaluated, under
>   certain    circumstances (see the let and declare builtin commands and
>   Arithmetic Expansion).  Evaluation is done in fixed-width    integers
>   with no check for over- flow, though division by 0 is    trapped and
>   flagged as an error.  The operators and their    precedence,
>   associativity, and values are the same as in the C    language.  The
>   following list of operators is grouped into    levels of
>   equal-precedence operators.  The levels are listed in    order of
>   decreasing precedence.
>   (...)
>
> expr?expr:expr
>
> conditional operator

And the reason that `resVar` is assigned `0` when you use `"Yop"` or
`"Nop"` is because such string is not a valid number in `bash` and
therefore it's evaluated to `0`. It's also explained in `man bash` in
the same paragraph:

> A null value evaluates to 0.

It's also explained in [this Wikipedia
article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Bash) if you find it
easier to read:

> A true ternary operator only exists for arithmetic expressions:
>
> ((result = condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false))
>
> For strings there only exist workarounds, like e.g.:
>
> result=$([ "$a" == "$b" ] && echo "value_if_true" || echo
>   "value_if_false")
>
> (where "$a" == "$b" can be any condition test, respective [, can
>   evaluate.)

Answer (score 1):

Arkadiusz already pointed out that ternary operators are an arithmetic feature in bash, not usable in strings. If you want this kind of functionality in strings, you can always use arrays:

```
$ arr=(Nop Yop)
$ declare -p arr
declare -a arr='([0]="Nop" [1]="Yop")'
$ numVar=5; numVal=5; resvar="${arr[$((numVar == numVal ? 1 : 0))]}"; echo "$resvar"
Yop
$ numVar=2; numVal=5; resvar="${arr[$((numVar == numVal ? 1 : 0))]}"; echo "$resvar"
Nop
```

Of course, if you're just dealing with two values that can be in position `0` and `1` in your array, you don't need the ternary; the following achieves the same thing:

```
$ resvar="${arr[$((numVar==numVal))]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this simple expression :

```
resVar=$([ numVar == numVal  ] && echo "Yop" || echo "Nop")
```

Comment: This isn't recommended. `&&` and `||` have the same precedence, so for this to work as expected, the second command *cannot* have an nonzero exit status. `a && b || c` will still run `c` if `b` fails, contrary to expectation. Use `if a; then b; else c; fi` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Running with Gohti's idea to make the script more readable:

```
#!/bin/bash 
declare -a resp='([0]="not safe" [1]="safe")'

temp=70; ok=$(( $temp > 60 ? 1 : 0 ))
printf "The temperature is $temp Fahrenheit, it is ${resp[$ok]} to go outside\n";

temp=20; ok=$(( $temp > 60 ? 1 : 0 ))
printf "The temperature is $temp Fahrenheit, it is ${resp[$ok]} to go outside\n";
```